# invalid stops, mt5 with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, metatrader5

I have this order made for sell:

```
def open_trade_sell2(action, symbol, lot, tp, deviation, ea_magic_number,comment):
                    '''https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py
                    '''
                    # prepare the buy request structure
                    symbol_info = get_info(symbol)
                    print("symbol info",symbol_info)

                    #symbol_info_tick_dict = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol)._asdict()
                    #for prop in symbol_info_tick_dict:
                    #        print("  {}={}".format(prop, symbol_info_tick_dict[prop]))
                   
                    if not mt5.initialize():
                        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
                        quit()
                    # display the last GBPUSD tick
                    lasttick=mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol)
                    print(lasttick)

                    if action == 'buy':
                        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY
                        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).ask
                        pass
                    elif action =='sell':
                        trade_type = mt5.ORDER_TYPE_SELL
                        
                        price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(symbol).bid
                        print(price)
                        pass
                    #point = mt5.symbol_info(symbol).point
                    if tp< price:
                        print("el precio mt5 es:", price)
                        tp=str(tp)
                        tp=tp[:8]
                        tp=float(tp)
                        now = time.time()
                        if comment == "5min":
                           el_tiempo = int(now + 300)
                        if comment == "15min":
                           el_tiempo = int(now + 900)
                        if comment == "30min":
                           el_tiempo = int(now + 1800)
                        if comment == "1hour":
                           el_tiempo = int(now + 3600)

                        buy_request = {
                            "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
                            "symbol": symbol,
                            "volume": lot,
                            "type": trade_type,
                            "price": price,
                            "sl": price + (price -tp),
                            "tp": tp,
                            "deviation": deviation,
                            "magic": ea_magic_number,
                            "comment": comment,
                            "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_SPECIFIED , # good till cancelled
                            "expiration": el_tiempo,
                            "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_IOC,
                        }
                        # send a trading request
                        result = mt5.order_send(buy_request)       
                        print("¿orden enviada?")    
                        print("resultado de la orden", result)  
                    else:
                        print("no puede vender")
                        result = "no posible comprar"
                        buy_request = "no posible comprar nene"
                    return result, buy_request
```

but when placing orders, it doesn't do them.

This are the order results:

```
OrderSendResult(retcode=10016, deal=0, order=0, volume=0.0, price=0.0, bid=0.0, ask=0.0, comment='Invalid stops', request_id=0, retcode_external=0, request=TradeRequest(action=1, magic=4494609, order=0, symbol='EURCHF', volume=0.1, price=0.97846, stoplimit=0.0, sl=0.978479, tp=0.978441, deviation=100, type=1, type_filling=1, type_time=2, expiration=1682463619, comment='1hour', position=0, position_by=0))
```

It comments that I have invalid stops, but sl and tp are correctly done. Im using robomarkets, python 3.7 and windows 11

Why am I having this problem? why aren't the orders made? how can I fix this?

this is the error:

```
symbol_info_tick() failed, error code = (1, 'Success')
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), don't paste the entire function. Isolate the logic that doesn't work and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76105772/edit)

Comment: thats the problem, I don't know whats not working ...

Comment: `price + price - tp` is always going to a result higher than the current price.  A stop loss price has to be below.